# Why am I being asked to defined a variable that already been defined?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve homework problem.

Flesh out the body of the print_seconds function so that it prints the total amount of seconds given the hours, minutes, and seconds function parameters. Remember that there are 3600 seconds in an hour and 60 seconds in a minute.

Here is what I have tried.

```
def print_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds):
    total_seconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds
print(total_seconds)
print_seconds(1,2,3)
```

I am getting this error message.

[image]

I dont understand why I am getting this error. I defined the variable inside the function.

Comment: _"I defined the variable inside the function."_ Correct. You did not, however, define any variable by that name _outside_ of the function, where `print(total_seconds)` is called. Do you mean to include the call to `print` inside of `print_seconds`?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...

Comment: Good reads - [Names, Objects, Scopes, and Namespaces in the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects). Also [Naming and Binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to indent the 2nd to last line `print(total_seconds)` like this, at the moment, it's out of scope.

```
def print_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds):
   total_seconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds
   print(total_seconds)

print_seconds(1,2,3)
```

Output:

```
3723
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting an error is because of a scope issue. You need to put the `print(total_seconds)` code in the `print_seconds()` function, like this:

```py
def print_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds):
    total_seconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds
    print(total_seconds)

print_seconds(1,2,3)
```